# Parse variable value from front end JS to the Node Serve.JS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodejs-server

How can I pass the variable skip value from front end JS to the Node Serve.JS file? Currently these are the codes that I have. Any idea where I have written wrongly?

Server.js (NodeJs)

```
app.get("/api/routes", function(req , res){
      // Configure the request
      const skip = req.query.skip;
      var options = {
          url: 'http://dataservice/trainroutes?$skip='+skip,
          method: 'GET',
          encoding: null,
          headers: {
              AccountKey: 'XXX',
              accept: 'application/json'
          }
      }

      request(options, function (error, response, body) {
          if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
              res.writeHead(200, response.headers);
              res.write(body);
              res.end();
          }
          else {
              res.send("Error");
          }
      })  
});
```

Front end JS:

```
function busseries(){
    var skip = 14000;

    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/routes?skip="+skip,
        success: function(results5) {
            //Set result to a variable for writing
            var objs5 = JSON.stringify(results5);
            var routetimeobjs5 = JSON.parse(objs5);
            console.log(routetimeobjs5)  
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Try adding  type: 'GET' in your Ajax Call. Also log req.query in the first line of your  server side function for better debugging.

Comment: @TusharShahi Implemented your suggestion. My skip variable value is '0' instead of '14000'

Comment: This should work actually, what is in the req body and is the param empty?

Comment: @Lawrence try passing the data parameter instead of the query method. Does it work now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it with template literals like so.

```
url: `/api/routes?skip=${skip}`
```

Comment: Currently My skip variable value is '0' instead of  the should pose '14000'

Comment: maybe something else is manipulating your var, change it to `const skip = 14000` and also try hardcoding `/api/routes?skip=14000` to see if it works, then go from there

Comment: What solved it? was it using template literals or using const?

Comment: Your initial suggestion and TusharShahi suggestion have already solved my question initially.  There was a conflicting variable value somewhere else in the non related code. Sorry for the confusion...